# Angular seeing wrong Typescript version

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

When I run `ng build` I get the following error:

> ERROR in The Angular Compiler requires TypeScript >=3.4.0 and <3.6.0 but 3.7.4 was found instead.

But in my `package.json`, I have defined `"typescript": "^3.5.3"`

I did a find in files in the project for `3.7.4` and it doesn't appear anywhere so why does Angular-CLI think that this is the version specified?

I am using node 12.13.0.

Here is my full `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "npm run build",
    "ng": "ng",
    "dev": "ng build --aot --watch",
    "dtos": "tsd-ref && ts-ref",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "publish": "npm run build",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "test": "ng test",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/common": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "^8.2.14",
    "@servicestack/angular": "0.0.8",
    "@servicestack/client": "^1.0.31",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "core-js": "^3.6.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.4",
    "zone.js": "^0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.21",
    "@angular/cli": "^8.3.21",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "^8.2.14",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.8",
    "@types/node": "^12.12.22",
    "codelyzer": "^5.2.1",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "jasmine-core": "^3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^4.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.0.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.1",
    "protractor": "^5.4.2",
    "ts-node": "^8.5.4",
    "tslint": "^5.20.1",
    "typescript": "^3.5.3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[npm semver docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/semver) explains the meanings of the different operators, e.g. [^Caret Ranges](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/semver#caret-ranges-123-025-004) allows upgrade up to the next major version.

You can use [~Tilde Ranges](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/semver#tilde-ranges-123-12-1) instead to allow patch level changes:

```
"typescript": "~3.5.3"
```

Or to specify to use an **exact version** you should specify the version number (which assumes an implied `=` default), e.g:

```
"typescript": "3.5.3"
```